# Apache rewrite to preserve query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a set of rules that rewrite URL depending on the affiliate. Everything works fine
However, I'm having a problem preserving the complete query string in URL.
Here's my rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*\.html) /adb.pl?code=${affcode:$1}&extra=%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]
```

The query in URL gets stripped after affcode.

URL should look like this:

```
http://mydomain.com?utm_campaign=TEST-AFF&utm_source=TEST-AFF&utm_medium=TEST-AFF&utm_term=TEST-AFF&utm_content=TEST-AFF-JON
```

Instead I'm getting this in my browser:

```
http://mydomain.com?utm_campaign=TEST-AFF
```

I have already tried using QSA and NE flags. But as long as [PT] is there it refuses to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?
It doesnt affect the browser, but it affect how the browser is showing the URL. I believe its due to ampersand in path.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" you are facing has nothing to do with `mod_rewrite`. You have a campaign in Google, right? All these `utm_something` are just for that. You have a JS from Google for this campaign, right?
So it works this way:
- JS takes these extra parameters from the query string
- then it redirects the browser to Google Analytics URL sending these parameters
- Google Analytics grabs this request and records the visit on your page coming from campaign
- GA sends HTTP redirect response to browser pointing to original URL stripped from all utm_something

Why? Because if they were not stripped, JS would grab them again and this will lead to endless loop of redirects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Elmo, you're on the right track with this one. 
It is indeed related to GA. I'll have to check with our devs on this one.