# Passing $_GET variables in virtual sub directory url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm pretty new to php and server side scripting. I've got this URL `example.com/category/catname
where catname directory is processed using **.htaccess Rewrite rule**

```
^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$    category.php?type=$1    [NC,L]
```

But when I use pagination variable

```
example.com/category/catname?page=2
```

i'm unable to access the $_GET['page'] variable on this. Please help.

Comment: Your rewrite rule is cutting off the query string vars

Comment: can you suggest a fix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache rewrite to preserve query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225302/apache-rewrite-to-preserve-query-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a custom function to get these variables if needed.

```
function process_requests(){
    $orig_URI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    list($null, $requests) = explode("?", $orig_URI);
    //cycle through our requests
    parse_str($requests, $res);
    return $res;
}
```

and use it like this: `$requests = process_requests();`

Access the items like this: `$requests['page'];`